# Need Help on Cross Object Look Up Field Update

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I finally have the Ids query corrected(after 20 years);

```
Select (Select ParentA__c From ChildA__r) 
From ParentB s 
WHERE Id IN (Select s.ParentB 
From ChildB s)
```

I now have the IDs I would need to populated the lookup field in ChildB.

The criteria would be if the ParentB Id of ChildB (Master-Detail) field = ParentB Id of ChildA ( Master Detail ) field

then

Get ParentA Id of that ChildA and populate the ParentA Id Lookup up field in ChildB.

( Hope it made a lot of sense )

[image]

Now the issue is I cannot get it to materialize.

Hope this is simple enough for a favor to ask.

How would you code this?
Specially the Upsert part?

Comment: #sfdcfox, please help? thanks !

Comment: So you have a Lookup Field on ChildB that you want to populate with the Id of ParentA? Where are you starting from? I.e. Are you currently dealing with a collection of ChildB records?

Comment: Yes, Yes ! 

I am really dumb on these so I really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your existing query result to a Map. This will allow you to quickly get the ParentB__c records by Id. Then you can access the ChildAs ParentA ID from the ChildA__r list.

```
Map<Id, ParentB__c> parentBsMap = new Map<Id, ParentB__c>([Select Id, (Select ParentA__c From ChildA__r) 
From ParentB__c s 
WHERE Id IN (Select s.ParentB__c From ChildB__c s)]);

for(ChildB cb : yourCollectionOfChildBRecords) {
     if(parentBsMap.containsKey(cb.ParentB__c)) {
         ParentB__c pb = parentBsMap.get(cb.ParentB__c);
         List<ChildA__c> cas = pb.ChildA__r;
         if(cas.size() > 0) {
             Id firstParentAId = cas[0].ParentA__c;
             // Set you lookup field here
             cb.ParentALookup__c = firstParentAId;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh My GOD ! It worked @Daniel Ballinger.

I big big THANK YOU !

You and fishofprey.com rocks BIG TIME !!!